# changing label's text by using tags

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Here is what I'd like to do.

I have 5 labels .  I would like to change attributes (background color), using a variable.  So if the variable (x) is equal to 3, it would change the background on label03.

At the same time, there will be 5 images .  I would change the attributes (alpha), using the same variable.  So if the variable (x) is equal to 3 like above, it would change the label03 background, and the alpha on image03.

What I'm missing is the way to choose the proper tag so (x) is pointing to what I need it to point to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do something like this:

```
// create an offset by control type (zero is not a good value here)
#define kLABEL_TAG_OFFSET  32
#define kIMAGE_TAG_OFFSET  64

// when creating the controls
UILabel *label0 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:...];
label0.tag = kLABEL_TAG_OFFSET + 0;

// and so on 0..3
label4.tag = kLABEL_TAG_OFFSET + 4;
imageView4.tag = kIMAGE_TAG_OFFSET + 4

// then, when you want to alter a particular image and label
//
- (void)setPropertiesOnControlsIndexedBy:(NSInteger)index {

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:kLABEL_TAG_OFFSET + index];
    UImageView *image = (UImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:kIMAGE_TAG_OFFSET + index];

    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    image.alpha = 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using a nib to create and position these elements, all you'll need to do is open the Attributes Inspector and set the tag for each of the labels and images. I would go with giving the labels a tag of 1x and the images a tag of 2x (where x is the number of the element). So the labels have tags 10-14 and the images have tags 20-24. Then in your viewController, if you have a int x, you can get the label and imageViews with the following lines.

```
UILabel *label = [self.view viewWithTag:10+x];
UIImageView *imageView = [self.view viewWithTag:20+x];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create/customize all the labels and images in the `viewDidLoad` and everytime you change the value of the variable, tell the view to reload.

```
 [someView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `-reloadData` when you want to change x, and have the default values set to x, so upon reload, they will automatically change.

```
- (void) xChanged {

    [self.tableView reloadData];    

}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) ip {

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image-%d", x]];
    cell.imageView.alpha = x;

}
```